# Apply a function on each image in a stack of images in XArray

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I have a stack of images, say

```
import dask.array as da
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

img_stack =  xr.DataArray(
    da.from_array(np.random.random((5,100,100))), 
    dims=('t','x','y'), 
    coords={'t':range(5),'x':range(100),'y':range(100)}
)
```

and a function:

```
def filter(patch, N=3):
    print(patch.shape)
    return signal.convolve2d(
           patch, (1 / (N * N)) * np.ones((N, N)), 
           boundary="symm", mode="same")
```

I want to apply this function of each of the images in the stack (along the `t` dimension).

I thought the best way to do this would be with `apply_ufunc` and I'm able to do this when `dask` isn't enabled:

```
xr.apply_ufunc(
    filter, img_stack.load(), 
    input_core_dims=[['y','x']], 
    output_core_dims=[['y','x']], vectorize=True)
```

This works fine and I get the desired result. The filter receives a `(100,100)` array.

But if I allow dask:

```
xr.apply_ufunc(
    filter, 
    img_stack, input_core_dims=[['y','x']], 
    output_core_dims=[['y','x']], vectorize=True, dask='allowed')
```

I end up with a `ValueError: convolve2d inputs must both be 2D arrays`.

Note: In this case, I didn't `load()` the dataset. If you have already loaded the dataset from executing the previous code block, might be good to reinitialize `img_stack` variable by running the first codeblock.

The array sent to the `filter` function has shape `(5,100,100)` as opposed to `(100,100)` in the previous case, and hence I land up with a error (since the method expects a `m X n` array). Not sure why this is happening, or what I can do to apply the `filter` function on each of the 5 images in the stack.

I'm wondering what's the best way to do this, and if I was applying `apply_ufunc` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are specifying `dask="allowed"`, which tells `xarray` that your function can handle dask arrays natively - which in you case it can't.

The [documentation states](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html#xarray-apply-ufunc):

> dask ({"forbidden", "allowed", "parallelized"}, default: "forbidden")
> – How to handle applying to objects containing lazy data in the form
> of dask arrays:
>
> ‘forbidden’ (default): raise an error if a dask array is encountered.
>
> ‘allowed’: pass dask arrays directly on to func. Prefer this option if
> func natively supports dask arrays.
>
> ‘parallelized’: automatically parallelize func if any of the inputs
> are a dask array by using dask.array.apply_gufunc. Multiple output
> arguments are supported. Only use this option if func does not
> natively support dask arrays (e.g. converts them to numpy arrays).

So you need to set `dask="parallelized"`, if you do your example will work.

Note that using `vectorize=True` works just fine, but it's not the most performant solution - particularly if your dataset gets bigger.
If performance is a concern for you, look into using `numab.guvectorize` to apply your function to each 1d element of a 3d array, like in this [lengthy xarray example](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/apply_ufunc_vectorize_1d.html).